# Create multiple deb packages from a single python project

Tags: python, linux, package, debian, deb

I have a Python project and I want to create two Debian packages out of this code, one for the project itself and the other for some data files.

My `debian/control` looks like this:

```
Source: demopackage
Section: web
Priority: extra
Maintainer: myself <myself@example.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 8.0.0), python (>=2.7), python-setuptools
Standards-Version: 3.9.3

Package: demopackage
Architecture: all
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python:Depends}
Description: A demo package
  This is the demo package

#Package: demopackage-test
#Architecture: all
#Depends: ${misc:Depends}, ${python:Depends}
#Description: demo package unit test
# This is the demo package's unit test package :)
```

and `debian/rules`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh $@ --buildsystem=python_distutils --with=python2
```

When I have a single package listed in `debian/control`, it gets created properly; when I uncomment the second package, I get two more or less empty packages, which is expected because `debuild` doesn't know which files belong to which package.

The question is what should I change in order to create one `demopackage` "python package" and one `demopackage-test` containing only `test/unit_test.py` (my data file for the second package) ?

Let me be more clear: the resulting `demopackage` should be identical to the one created by `debuild` when I only have one package listed in `debian/control` (i.e. it contains the code installed in `/usr/share/pyshared`, symlinks created in `/usr/lib/python2.7/...` etc.) .

`demopackage-test` I can handle myself, I'll just add a `debian/demopackage-test.install` file, but I don't know what to do about `demopackage`.

You can download the package test code [here](http://wikisend.com/download/510538/demopackage.tar.bz2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mostly got the answer- `dh_install` is the simple way to specify which files go where.

If you can easily enumerate the files and/or directories that you want to go in `demopackage`, then creating a `debian/demopackage.install` file will take care of the problem. For many python packages, it ends up sufficient to have a line like

```
/usr/lib/python2.*/*-packages/whatever
```

However, if you need more flexibility than `dh_install` can provide, you may want to use some explicit shell commands instead, or in addition to `dh_install`. For example, to make *everything* that gets installed to `debian/tmp` go in `demopackage` except for the one test/unit_test.py file, you might put this stanza in `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_install:
        dh_install
        cp -a debian/tmp/* debian/demopackage/
        rm debian/demopackage/usr/share/whatever/unit_test.py
```

You can pretty much do whatever you want to put the right files into the right places, as long as you don't pull in files from outside of the build tree, and all the tools you use along the way are accounted for by the build dependencies.